# How can I change the redirect url of a checkout page from the embed button code?

Tags: javascript, html, xcode, button, return-value

Please, how do I integrate external payment gateway into a native app. For instance, I created a donation button in paypal. After donation, the user is supposed to be redirected to a page within the app. I don't know I can go about this. The only way I figured out is to customize the embed code of the donation button, may be by using javascript or some sort of codes, so that user can be redirected to my desired page within the native app.
Please, what code can I add to the embed button code, and where should I add it, so that the user can be redirected to my desired page within the app after payment?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code for redirection according to condition based

```
<script>
function renderPage(redirectType){
if(redirectType=="google"){
window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
}else if(redirectType=="yahoo"){
window.location.href="http://yahoo.com";
}else{
//Default page
window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
}

}


</script>
```

invoke renderPage(redirectType) and passing parameter accoring to your choice.